# Mongoose subdocuments return different ID every time

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

I have a model Franchise that has another Schema Employee as its subdocuments for a field. The structure is as follows.

Franchise.js

```
const Franchise = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        franchiseName: String,
        address: String,
        managers: [Employee]
    });


export default mongoose.model(
    "Franchise",
    Franchise
);
```

Employee.js

```
const Employee = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    name: String,
    email: String,
    phoneNo: Number,
    password: String,
});
```

export default Employee;

The issue I am facing is with every query to Franchise, it returns a new _id for the objects in managers field. Is there any way to make it constant ?

For instance, I am running a simple findById on Franchise and store it in franchise variable.
and then I console.log(franchise.managers).

It prints different IDs each time the query is run.

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("61925d2697852574eb0ba9ab"),
    name: 'Franchise Manager 1',
    email: 'franchise1@sfc.com',
    phoneNo: 1234567890,
  }
]
```

Second time the query is run:

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("61925ba8130aca93a7dd3dbc"),
    name: 'Franchise Manager 1',
    email: 'franchise1@sfc.com',
    phoneNo: 1234567890
  }
]
```

As you can see, the employee is the same, however it has different Id for each call. Kindly help.
Thanks.

Comment: Why you are not exporting Employee as mongoose.model

Comment: @Alghazali505 Doing so results in this error.
TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `model` is not a valid type within the array `managers`.See https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#definition for a list of valid schema types.

Comment: yes, because you need to import Employee schema in Franchise.js first.

Comment: A good practice to name Schemas like that "FranchiseSchema", "EmployeeSchema"

Comment: @Alghazali505 I am importing the other schema. Anyways, I solved my issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out. The issue is that there was no _id stored in the database for existing data of managers. The Employee schema was added later on, so as the _id was not present in the database only, a new one was being generated each time.

Comment: So what do you do to solve this problem, i have same issue